# Vue js babel build error after installing prerender-spa-plugin

Tags: javascript, vue.js, babeljs, prerender

So I have a vue-js application and today I started using prerender-spa-plugin to generate some static pages for better SEO. When I run npm run build, everything works perfect, no errors. Now when I want to run the development server with npm run serve, I get the following error (only a part of it)

```
 error  in ./src/main.js

 Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel- 
 loader/lib/index.js):
 Error: .plugins[0] must include an object
at assertPluginItem (/Users/user/Desktop/app/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/validation/option-assertions.js:231:13)
```

So I guess the problem has to do with the babel plugin loader. So I commended every part of my code using prerender-spa-plugin, but I still get the same error. I hope someone can point me to the right direction.

My babel.config.js

```
const removeConsolePlugin = []
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
 removeConsolePlugin.push("transform-remove-console")
 }


module.exports = {
 presets: [
'@vue/app'
],
  plugins: [removeConsolePlugin]
}
```

My vue.config.js

```js
const path = require('path');
const PrerenderSpaPlugin = require('prerender-spa-plugin');

const productionPlugins = [
  new PrerenderSpaPlugin({
    staticDir: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    routes: ['/', '/documentation'],
    renderer: new PrerenderSpaPlugin.PuppeteerRenderer({
      // We need to inject a value so we're able to
      // detect if the page is currently pre-rendered.
      inject: {},
      // Our view component is rendered after the API
      // request has fetched all the necessary data,
      // so we create a snapshot of the page after the
      // `data-view` attribute exists in the DOM.
      //renderAfterElementExists: '[data-view]',
    }),
  }),
];


module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: (config) => {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
      config.plugins.push(...productionPlugins);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I just had to remove the [] around removeConsolePlugin

Comment: please provide answer your question if you have found the solution in order to help others